# can't run a server because node package errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, package.json

M1 Mac user here. Trying to run a server to work on website in dev environment, but something is off with node packages and maybe next.js versioning?.. I tried updating them with `npm install` but I keep running into this error:

```
bash-3.2$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: pulse@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: next@10.0.7
npm ERR! node_modules/next
npm ERR!   next@"12.1.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! next@"12.1.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0-0" from next@12.1.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/next
npm ERR!     next@"12.1.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/artemhb/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/artemhb/.npm/_logs/2022-05-28T21_24_07_001Z-debug-0.log
```

This is what happens when I try running a server anyway:

```
bash-3.2$ npm run dev

> pulse@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/parser' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/artemhb/Documents/hbdev/impulse/node_modules/postcss/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:439:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:718:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.552 (/Users/artemhb/Documents/hbdev/impulse/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11590)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (/Users/artemhb/Documents/hbdev/impulse/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)
    at Object.270 (/Users/artemhb/Documents/hbdev/impulse/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:400)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (/Users/artemhb/Documents/hbdev/impulse/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)
    at Object.327 (/Users/artemhb/Documents/hbdev/impulse/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:260)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (/Users/artemhb/Documents/hbdev/impulse/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)
    at Object.845 (/Users/artemhb/Documents/hbdev/impulse/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:3733) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
```

Any recommendations on what to do here?  Thanks!

**UPD**: Before running a server, I tried to install / update new packages, and here's what I got –

```
# npm resolution error report

2022-05-28T22:19:21.808Z

While resolving: pulse@0.1.0
Found: react@18.1.0
node_modules/react
  react@"18.1.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-lazyload@3.2.0
node_modules/react-lazyload
  react-lazyload@"^3.2.0" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "react",
    "version": "18.1.0",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "pulse",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "path": "/Users/artemhb/Documents/hbdev/impulse"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/react",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "react",
        "spec": "18.1.0",
        "from": {
          "location": "/Users/artemhb/Documents/hbdev/impulse"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "currentEdge": {
    "type": "prod",
    "name": "react",
    "spec": "18.1.0",
    "from": {
      "location": "/Users/artemhb/Documents/hbdev/impulse"
    }
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "react",
    "spec": "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "react-lazyload",
      "version": "3.2.0",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "pulse",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "path": "/Users/artemhb/Documents/hbdev/impulse"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/react-lazyload",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "prod",
          "name": "react-lazyload",
          "spec": "^3.2.0",
          "from": {
            "location": "/Users/artemhb/Documents/hbdev/impulse"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a minimal example that will produce this error and add the code to your questions (e.g. package.json, folder structure, main files,...)? Or describe the steps that you did to create the project? With-out seeing more details it is difficult to help. But I'd check the package.json and maybe adding `next@"12.1.6"` could help...

Comment: Screenshot of package.json file (from Source Control) – https://tppr.me/RYq0h

Comment: You can use: npm install --force